# Co-ordinate conversion

Tags: vb6

I am making a simple coordinate converter with the help of eye4software. Following link provides the required Visual Basic 6 codes for the converter.

http://www.eye4software.com/products/gpstoolkit/source/vb/datumtransformation/

I have followed said process according to the given details in the link.

```vb-all
Private Sub Form1_Load()

    Private objProjection As GpsProjection

    Private objDatumSrc As GpsDatumParameters

    Private objDatumDst As GpsDatumParameters

    Set objProjection = CreateObject("Eye4Software.GpsProjection")

    Set objDatumSrc = CreateObject("Eye4Software.GpsDatumParameters")

    Set objDatumDst = CreateObject("Eye4Software.GpsDatumParameters")

End Sub

Option Explicit


Private objProjection As GpsProjection

Private objDatumSrc As GpsDatumParameters

Private objDatumDst As GpsDatumParameters


Private Sub CommandTranslate_Click()

    ' Set Source Datum ( WGS84 )
    ' The ID for WGS84 is 4326, see 'http://www.eye4software.com/resources/datums' for a full list of supported datums
    ' To convert from another datum, just change the code below (EPSG code)
    objDatumSrc.LoadFromId (4326)

    ' Set Destination Datum ( NAD27 )
    ' The ID for NAD27 is 4267, see 'http://www.eye4software.com/resources/datums' for a full list of supported datums
    ' To convert to another datum, just change the code below (EPSG code)
    objDatumDst.LoadFromId (4267)

    ' Set Source coordinates
    objProjection.Latitude = CDbl(Textlat1.Text)
    objProjection.Longitude = CDbl(Textlon1.Text)

    ' Perform the datum transformation
    objProjection.TransformDatum objDatumSrc, objDatumDst

    ' Display the result
    Textlat2.Text = objProjection.Latitude
    Textlon2.Text = objProjection.Longitude
End Sub
```

But i am getting a run time error for this code ***(objDatumSrc.LoadFromId (4326))*** saying object required. Since i'm a beginner i was unable to solve this. please help me.

Comment: Minor point but [don't put brackets around procedure parameters](http://hashvb.earlsoft.co.uk/Brackets_around_procedure_parameters). It may not be the cause for the problem here, but it will bite you at some point (with the same error)

Answer (score 1):

You have two `objDatumSrc` variables.

- One is a private variable inside `Form_Load` - you are initialising that one.
- The other one is a module-level one and you are not initialising that one.

Delete the `Private` variable declarations inside `Form_Load`

Answer (score 0):

To me, it looks like you aren't understanding scope, but the real problem is a non-instantiated variable. Your declaration of objDatumSrc in the form load event will not be able to be seen in the rest of the form because The variables you are declaring outside of a method are not being instantiated.

Replace your current code with this...

```
Option Explicit

Private objProjection As New GpsProjection
Private objDatumSrc As New GpsDatumParameters
Private objDatumDst As New GpsDatumParameters

Private Sub CommandTranslate_Click()
    ' Set Source Datum ( WGS84 )
    ' The ID for WGS84 is 4326, see 'http://www.eye4software.com/resources/datums' for a full list of supported datums
    ' To convert from another datum, just change the code below (EPSG code)
    objDatumSrc.LoadFromId (4326)

    ' Set Destination Datum ( NAD27 )
    ' The ID for NAD27 is 4267, see 'http://www.eye4software.com/resources/datums' for a full list of supported datums
    ' To convert to another datum, just change the code below (EPSG code)
    objDatumDst.LoadFromId (4267)

    ' Set Source coordinates
    objProjection.Latitude = CDbl(Textlat1.Text)
    objProjection.Longitude = CDbl(Textlon1.Text)

    ' Perform the datum transformation
    objProjection.TransformDatum objDatumSrc, objDatumDst

    ' Display the result
    Textlat2.Text = objProjection.Latitude
    Textlon2.Text = objProjection.Longitude
End Sub
```

Comment: I've updated my answer after further review and simply posted the code that you should be using.

Answer (score 0):

The code here so obviously shouldn't compile, it is obvious that you are not showing your real code. For instance, what is your error handling? If you have done something like On Error Resume Next, then if the following lines raise errors, then the errors won't be reported.

```
Set objProjection = CreateObject("Eye4Software.GpsProjection")
Set objDatumSrc = CreateObject("Eye4Software.GpsDatumParameters")   
Set objDatumDst = CreateObject("Eye4Software.GpsDatumParameters")
```

Since they would be set to Nothing, if you tried to execute methods and properties on objProjection, objDatumSrc, and objDatumDst, they would raise the error "object required".

And since this is likely not the code you have tried to run, can you verify that all the Program Ids e.g. "Eye4Software.GpsProject" are correct? In fact - have you registered these components? And why can't you instantiate these objects using the slightly cleaner notation, e.g.

```
Set objProjection = New Eye4Software.GpsProjection
```

?

Comment: You'd get "Object or with block not set", not "Object Required".

Answer (score -1):

Try either:

```
Call objDatumSrc.LoadFromId(4326)
```

or

```
objDatumSrc.LoadFromId  4326
```

VB gets a little funky doing method calls with parameters.  If it's not in the expected format, some results may vary.